# My wp database has been hacked

Tags: plugins, database, plugin-w3-total-cache

My database has hacked by someone and removed it. But my site still working because of W3 Total Cache. Is there any way to get old database by using W3 Total Cache?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. W3 Total Cache only caches the full HTML generated by a page after the database was queried. It does not keep any information about what data was in the database.

Comment: @JacobPeattie do you know anything else can do to recover the database?

Comment: You would need to check with your host if they have a backup. If they don't, then you're out of luck.

Comment: If your content was public, like a blog, then http://web.archive.org/ can help you to get some of them, if lost entirely. Good luck

Comment: You may also be able to do a Google site:yourdomain.com to see Google's cache, if you act quickly.

Comment: @WebElaine I have recovered most of the data through google cache. Thank you very much all of you.